# Why am I receiving 50 code from QOSStartTrackingClient method?

Tags: winapi, msdn, qos

I am receiving error code `50` from the code below, which means `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

I use the `QOSStartTrackingClient` method from [this winapi document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374048(v=vs.85).aspx). But it does not say when do I receive this result.

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin { AF_INET };                
inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", &(sin.sin_addr.s_addr));

if (!QOSStartTrackingClient(QoSHandle, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, 0))
   cout << GetLastError();
```

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: "*The qWave subsystem cannot track information about the destination you've specified. It could be that the other host does does not have the required components or that it is not on the same link.*"

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername So how can I track the flows of the socket from another application?

Comment: Have no idea, just added the comment from the header file that doesn't seem to be present in the official documentation (that you mention)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Alright. Post it as the answer.